# Indenting the first line of figure captions

Tags: floats, captions, indentation, paragraphs

I want to create a small indentation in the first line of figure captions, similar to the way LaTeX indents the first line of paragraphs.

The `caption` package does not seem to support this.

Is it doable?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Yes, it's doable, but I'm not sure it's typographically sound. The keyword "Figure" or "Table" provides the visual clue for identifying the caption.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `caption` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\newlength\myindention
\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}%
{\hspace*{\myindention}#1#2#3}
\setlength\myindention{1cm}
\captionsetup{format=myformat}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{White sand beaches. The pink smoothness of the conch shell. A sea abundant
  with possibilities. Duty-free shops filled with Europe’s finest gifts and perfumes. Play
  your favorite game of golf amidst the tropical greens on one of the many championship
  courses.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}​
```

[image]

The above method is applicable to `table`s also.

As noted by **Gonzalo**, this can be also done by using the available options of `caption` package as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{format=hang,indention=-60pt,margin=20pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{White sand beaches. The pink smoothness of the conch shell. A sea abundant
  with possibilities. Duty-free shops filled with Europe’s finest gifts and perfumes. Play
  your favorite game of golf amidst the tropical greens on one of the many championship
  courses.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}​
```

Comment: You can also do this without declaring a new format, and using the predefined options with something like `\captionsetup[figure]{format=hang,indention=-60pt,margin=20pt}`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: True. But I wanted to avoid that and introduce a custom style. Anyway, I feel that it is a welcome addition. I will add it to the answer.

Comment: After seeing the result I'm even more convinced that this should *not* be done. ;-)

Comment: @egreg: I believe it is a very common convention in scientific journals and in articles therein. It may, however, not be an ideal format for larger works such as books and theses.

Answer (score 5):

In the standard document classes, you can redefine the macro that prints the caption, called `\@makecaption`.

I've defined `\captionindent` to be the same as the default `\parindent`. The reason for storing it in a different length is because captions are usually set with no `\parindent`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newlength{\captionindent}\setlength{\captionindent}{\parindent}
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \sbox\@tempboxa{#1: #2}%
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
    \hspace*{\captionindent}#1: #2\par% Added \captionindent
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{White sand beaches. The pink smoothness of the conch shell. A sea abundant
  with possibilities. Duty-free shops filled with Europe’s finest gifts and perfumes. Play
  your favorite game of golf amidst the tropical greens on one of the many championship
  courses.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}​
```

This will hold for all captions. An alternative solution may be provided if you're using the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption).